# windows form sometimes freez when looping all item in gridvi

Tags: vb.net

Trying to save all rows in DataGridView using `For Each` loop and the application sometimes freezes while I am not saving any rows. How can I solve this problem?

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(cs)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "[Stored_invoice]"
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        cmd.Connection = con
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgwold.Rows
            If Not row.IsNewRow Then
                If IsDBNull(row.Cells(6).Value) Then
                    xv = row.Cells(6).Value
                Else
                    xv = DBNull.Value
                End If
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", 0)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoice_id", invid)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpireDate", xv)
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: You're executing a new, individual query for every row in your `dgwold`. Queries take time. It'd would be better to build a single query (stored procedure) that builds the result set you need on the database server. Each query comes with significant overhead from network latency, database server execution time, etc. Your approach of running a query per row is nearly never necessary and always a bad idea.

Comment: thank you for your replay , the stored procedure insert row into database for each row then how can i insert all row in gridview

Comment: Have a look at table adapters.  Think that’s what you’re after